# How can I catch the current node object and make changes into it before it is rendered?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I have a content type with multiple fields.

On the node display page I want to do some modification on this node (like. changing label text etc.) and I want to do it for display only. Nothing should change in the database.

I want to know how can I do this? Where exactly can I catch the current node object and make changes into it before it is rendered?

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_node_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)

> This hook is called after the content has been assembled in a structured array and may be used for doing processing which requires that the complete node content structure has been built.
>
> If the module wishes to act on the rendered HTML of the node rather than the structured content array, it may use this hook to add a #post_render callback. Alternatively, it could also implement `hook_preprocess_node()`. See [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) and [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) documentation respectively for details.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the preprocess hook for this task.

For example, you can add in your theme :

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && $variables['node']->type == 'your_node_type') {
    // Change the $variables['node'] whatever you want here
  }
}
```